# Load date from local database into list, error

Tags: c#

I have a local database with 2 columns. One is an integer datatype and the other is datetime datatype.

I can successfully load data into the database with following code:

```
dataIn = myPort.ReadLine();
dt = DateTime.Now;

dbConnection.Open();

using (var insertCmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Measurements (Distance,DateTime) VALUES (@Distance,@DateTime)", dbConnection))
{
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Distance", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataIn;
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
    insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

dbConnection.Close();
```

But when running the code below, to select some data and add it to a list, I get the following error.

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
DateTime sdate = new DateTime();
SqlDataReader reader;
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Measurements where DateTime between '" + today + "' And '" + yearAgo + "'", dbConnection);
dbConnection.Open();

reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    sdate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("DateTime"));
    dates.Add(sdate);
    textBox1.AppendText(sdate.ToString());
}

reader.Close();
dbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: You have to parse the input string as a date. Otherwise, don't specify your column types and you can pass in strings-- SQL Server would then interpret the strings into the data type. I believe that used a command like `insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@paramname', 'value')` the last time I used it.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  All your queries should look like the first block.

Comment: If the first column has an  integer datatype, why are you adding a `string` as `VarChar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you should not be using string concatenation to build your select query. You should be using a parameterized query, just like you do when inserting. This will not only eliminate the formatting issue that is likely causing the exception you're seeing, but also protect you from [SQL Injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
DateTime sdate = new DateTime();
SqlDataReader reader;
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Measurements where DateTime betweeen @today AND @yearAgo", dbConnection);
dbConnection.Open();

selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("today", today);
selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("yearAgo", yearAgo);

reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
   sdate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("DateTime"));
   dates.Add(sdate);
   textBox1.AppendText(sdate.ToString());
}
reader.Close();
dbConnection.Close();
```

As a side note, the query as you've written it will never return results. You are requesting every record created on or after `@today` AND on or before `@yearAgo`. It's like asking for every number greater than or equal to 10 AND less than or equal to 5; any number greater than or equal to 10 cannot be less than or equal to 5. You need to flip the `@today` and `@yearAgo` parameters in your query.

`"SELECT * FROM Measurements where DateTime between @yearAgo and @today"`

Comment: Thanks man, it works now. I will heed what you say about parameterized queries. Still learning you know :D thanks again!